# Como organizar aplicação multi-nível MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação seguindo o padrão MVC, e terá 2 níveis de usuários, o normal e o admin, no que se refere as opções do que cada usuário pode fazer, é melhor fazer uma lógica no controller para mostrar determinada view ou alguma ação de outro controller ou criar alguns "blocos if" numa view padrão para "esconder" menus somente do admin ou vice/versa?

> Exemplo de situação:
>
> Um usuário normal acessa a dashboard depois do login, o ideal seria
> mostrar uma view **(views/user_normal)** específica para ele, que só tem os menus/links do seu
> nível, ou usar uma view **(views/all_users)** para ambos os níveis e esconder menus/links
> com validações?

Answer (score 1):

Um controller pode ter N views. Se acha melhor uma view para cada caso (user normal e admin), não tem problema. Mas tanto faz usar uma só view com condicionais ou múltiplas views.
Particularmente prefiro views separadas se houver muitas condicionais.

Há quem prefira um padrão estrito, ou seja, não importa se tem apenas 1 condicional, deve seguir o padrão de múltiplas views.

Quem define o padrão é o gerente do projeto.

Answer (score 1):

Para fugir de **(if/elses)** desnecessários pelo controller, eu prefiro fazer da maneira pelo qual você citou:

**view/user_normal**

**view/user_diferenciado**

É questão de boas práticas de código, mas nesse caso, pra mim é questão pessoal de quem está desenvolvendo.